# make size of container adjustable with element

Tags: html, css

I am self-learner. In HTML and CSS, I've created a div with id container and in that container, I've created two div. One for writing a paragraph. now i want to set the background colour for parent div container. but when i set container's height to auto, colour is not implementing.
here I've to make height =auto because, in child div, i am writing a paragraph.
So it should be adjustable.
how to make this correct?
here is my CSS code:

```
#container{
  height:auto;
  background: #6b6bd4;
}
```

and two child div are main and nav:

```
#main{
   background-color: beige;
   width:600px;
   float:right;
   padding-right: 15px;
}

#nav{    
   background-color: beige;
   width:180px;
   float:left;
   padding-left: 9px;    
}
```

HTML CODE:

### Welcome!

A lot of individuals seem to think that filing tax returns is voluntary and therefore dismiss it as unnecessary and burdensome. As we will see, this is not a very healthy perspective on tax-filing.

```
                        Filing tax returns is an annual activity seen as a moral and social duty of every responsible citizen of the country. It is the basis for the government to determine the amount and means of expenditure of the citizens and provides a platform for the assesse to claim refund, among other forms of relief from time to time.


                </p>
            </div>
            <div id ="nav">
                <h3>Useful Links</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Tax Calculator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Tax Forms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Tax Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Help Centre</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>`
```

Comment: this might help to start understanding floatting behaviors : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ ;)

Comment: We are all self-learners :). And here to help.

Comment: Please add the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, floats are very tricky and, IMHO, usually used incorrectly. 5+ years ago, floats were the next best thing to achieving a layout where two block-level elements could be displayed next to each other without using a `<table>` and columns.

The problem with using `float` is that it breaks the child elements out of the parent container element and treats them as if they are in their own rendering context. Meaning, the parent container suddenly treats its height as if there were no contents inside of it.

Today, you've got some better options available. One in particular is to use `display: flex` on your parent container, and `flex-direction: row`. This will retain the child elements within the parent container, allowing the parent container's height to be calculated appropriately.

[I recommend checking out flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

If you're concerned about which browsers this property is compatible with, it has very good support. [Check out caniuse for a compatibility matrix](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#nav, #main {
  width: 50%;
}

#nav {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 220, 120, 0.5);
}

#main {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 120, 220, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='nav'>Nav (100px height)</div>
  <div id='main'>Main (200px height)</div>
</div>
```